# Recursively cat files in subdirectories and name concatenated file on the name of initial of the files getting concatenated

Tags: linux

I have no background of shell script. I would like to perform the concatenation of files in all subdirectories recursively, which I was able to achieve by the help of previous posts on stack overflow. But I am unable to name the concatenated file on the name of files which are getting concatenated e.g.

Subdirectories:

Sample_001

Sample_002

Sample_003

Sample_004

Files in sub directory: Sample_001:

Sample_001-123_R1_001.fastq.gz

Sample_001-123_R1_002.fastq.gz

I used command :

For d in ./*/; do( cd "$d" && cat *R1* > d_R1.fastq); done

My question is how I can use 001 from my file name instead of d in "d_R1.fastq".

I was unable to understand how I can achieve this and where I should put another command in the loop I was using.

Thank you in advance for kind help.

Comment: Can you explain exactly what kind of output you are looking for, based on the examples provided?  Also, you might want to format your code in this post, remembering that shell commands tend to be case sensitive.  And I think you might be missing a $ (`cat R1 > $d_R1.fastq`)

Comment: My file name is

Comment: My file name is: Sample_001-R1001.fastq.gz. I want my output file to use the 001 from my file name "Sample_001" omitting the "Sample". Output file should have name: 001_R1.fastq. Should I use the command: for d in ./*/ do ( cd "$d" && $( cat *R1* > $d_R1.fastq)); done.??